# How to get file created date using fs module?

Tags: node.js, linux, fs

I have linux server where i have logs file that are being created with winston rotation , so `filename` has filename and created date, so you can see first file in `data` `server20170414181405.log` created on `2017-04-14` but using `fs.stats.birthtime` its giving fileDate `Apr-19-2017`. How can i get accurate file created date working on linux ?

cron.js

```
fs.stat(filePath, function (err, stats) {
  if (err) return cb2(err);
   var fileInfo = { fileDate: stats.birthtime, filename: file };
    console.log(fileInfo);
});
```

data

```
  { fileDate: Wed Apr 19 2017 00:51:56 GMT-0400 (EDT),
    filename: 'server20170414181405.log' },
  { fileDate: Wed Apr 19 2017 00:52:04 GMT-0400 (EDT),
    filename: 'server20170414212655.log' },
  { fileDate: Wed Apr 19 2017 00:52:07 GMT-0400 (EDT),
    filename: 'server20170415023845.log' },
```

Answer (score 0):

The stat.birthtime is the real date of file creation in server timezone. Probably the difference happens because Winston and your server are working in different timezones.

If is not the case to align both timezones, and you need of the stat.birthtime in some specific timezone, you can use [moment-timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/) date constructor.

Comment: The dates he's using are 5 days apart. That's a big timezone difference!  :)

Answer (score 0):

Getting the real file creation time has been difficult. The linux kernel only recently started supporting it, so I don't know how accurate the `birthtime` value is going to be. It may depend on the version of linux you are using. There is some background in this post:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/304779/is-there-still-no-linux-kernel-interface-to-get-file-creation-date

However, you are adding the creation time to the file name. Instead of using `fs.stat()`, why not just parse the file name and create a `Date` object from that?

```
const filename = 'server20170414181405.log';
const dateString = filename.substr(6, 4) + '-' + filename.substr(10, 2) 
    + '-' + filename.substr(12, 2) + 'T' + filename.substr(14, 2) 
    + ':' + filename.substr(16, 2) + ':' + filename.substr(18, 2);

// '2017-04-14T18:14:05'    
const createDate = new Date(dateString);
```

You can either add `Z` to the end for UTC or the correct timezone offset, for whatever timezone you are using in the filename. Of course, this assumes that your filenames are accurate, but, if so, it seems easier, and faster, than using `fs.stat()`.

**-- EDIT --**

It looks like you already have the path to the file in the `filePath` variable, so you can get the file name using the `path.basename()` method:

```
const path = require('path');

const filename = path.basename(filePath);
```

See the Node docs here: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/path.html#path_path_basename_path_ext. Once you have the file name, you can use the code in my original post to get the date.

Comment: i am trying to understand how you are parsing date without using filename variable

Comment: @hussain I'm not sure I understand what you are asking. I have edited my post. Please take a look and see if that helps.

Comment: you are not using `filename` variable to parse date, what is happening when you do `s.substr(6,4)` how it will get date from filename ?

Comment: @hussain Ah, okay, now I see the mistake! Sorry, just a typo. I copied the sample code from my Node REPL and forgot to change the variable name. I have corrected it.